# radio button value shows 0 even after changing it to other values (using JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to show my radio button value when its selection is changed in JQuery. But, no matter whatever value I assign to the radio button, it shows up only 0 in my alert box. I have tried so many things, but didn't get any luck.

Here is my Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      $("input[name='sec_officer']").change(function(){
        if ($("input[@name='sec_officer']:checked").val() == '5'){
          alert($("input[@name='sec_officer']:checked").val()); 
        } else 
            {alert($("input[@name='sec_officer']:checked").val()); }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML code segment:

```
<tr>
               <td>Security Officer oversight:</td>
               <td><input type="radio" name="sec_officer" id="sec_officer_no" value="5" checked="checked"/>
                No   <input type="radio" name="sec_officer" id="sec_officer_yes" value="6" />
                Yes</td>                
             </tr>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have those '@' symbols, but it works for me without them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      $("input[name='sec_officer']").change(function(){
        if ($("input[name='sec_officer']:checked").val() == '5'){
          alert($("input[name='sec_officer']:checked").val()); 
        } else 
            {alert($("input[name='sec_officer']:checked").val()); }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey @Churro, Thanks a ton. It worked for me too. The reason I used it because I tried without it in some other radio selection and it didn't work for me, so I read somewhere and I tried that and it worked for me. So same thing I tried to do here.

Answer (score 2):

The selected elment is returned as this. So you can do like this.

```
  $("input[name='sec_officer']").change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val()); // Checked value
  })
```

Edit:
[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ogoyik/7/edit)

```
  $("input[name='sec_officer']").change(function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    if(value==5) console.log("You selected 5");
    else console.log("You selected " + value);
  });
```

Comment: I got it what you are trying to say. But, removing '@' solved my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/u4uz3/)

`$("input[@name='sec_officer']` changed to `$("input[name='sec_officer']`

Removed `@` symbol and it worked

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='sec_officer']").change(function () {
        if ($("input[name='sec_officer']:checked").val() == '5') {
            alert($("input[name='sec_officer']:checked").val());
        } else {
            alert($("input[name='sec_officer']:checked").val());
        }
    });
});
```

if you only want to alert selected value you can use the below code

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='sec_officer']").change(function () {
        alert($("input[name='sec_officer']:checked").val());
    });
});
```

or this one

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='sec_officer']").change(function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this? I just removed '@' symbol at `$("input[@name=`. '@' is not needed there.

The code below is working here http://jsfiddle.net/E44JD/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      $("input[name='sec_officer']").change(function(){
      if ($("input[name='sec_officer']:checked").val() == '5'){
          alert($("input[name='sec_officer']:checked").val()); 
      } else {
          alert($("input[name='sec_officer']:checked").val()); 
      }
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey artsylar, I tried it and it did work for me. Thanks a lot.